# Cannot grab list box using Visual Basic in a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

My goal for what I am trying to do overall is have one box on a document that holds a database type and when someone select that database type the document will hide/show certain sections.

Well my issue right now is that I cannot seem to grab the the list box ContentControl I created.

I have a listbox ContentControl with a tag boxDB.

Currently this is all that I can get

```
Sub ListBox_AfterUpdate()

 Dim box
 Set box = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("boxDB")


End Sub
```

I have tried several things with box to try and get it to have data. My first assumption was that since it is a collection I would just find the first item by using the first index of the items..but it always says that there is no item at that index.

Is there another method I should be using to grab the value that was set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access the control and it's features by tag, read the [reference documentation for `SelectContentControlsByTag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.selectcontentcontrolsbytag). This shows that the returned object is a ***collection*** of controls that match the tag, so clearly you might have several controls with the same tag string.

You will help yourself quite a lot by [always using `Option Explicit`](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) in all your code and by specifically declaring each variable with a type. That way you can use the Intellisense feature of the VBA Editor to reveal what methods and properties are available as you write your code.

Assuming that your `ContentControl` is already established with the tag (and that you only have one control with that tag

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetupListbox()
    Dim theControls As ContentControls
    Dim box As ContentControl
    Set theControls = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("boxDB")
    Set box = theControls.Item(1)
    box.DropdownListEntries.Add "Red"
    box.DropdownListEntries.Add "Green"
    box.DropdownListEntries.Add "Blue"
    box.DropdownListEntries.Add "Yellow"
    box.DropdownListEntries.Add "Orange"
End Sub

Sub GetSelectedItem()
    Dim theControls As ContentControls
    Dim box As ContentControl
    Set theControls = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("boxDB")
    Set box = theControls.Item(1)
    Debug.Print box.Range.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I swear I tried some form of these but I must have missed a step. This does exactly what I need and I think I can now get a lot more done. I greatly appreciate the help!